# How can the placement of data points in a graph be adjusted?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

As part of an important presentation, I've created the following diagram showing statistical data over 5 periods of time.

[image: http://gflemming.de/graph.PNG]

The data for each period consists a pair of a bar charts with a corresponding dot for each bar.

**Now, here's my question:**

Does anybody know how to place the dots directly above their respective bars instead of centered in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot series needs to be an XY/ScatterChart type.  Then, just adjust your dot series X values to match your series position.

In your example, assuming that your XY chart is on the primary axis, you should set:

- First blue dot X value approx.
  0.85, then add 1 for each additional dot
- First yellow dot X value 1.15, then add 1 for each additional dot

[image: align dots]